# Ords installation issue in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ords

After ords installation in SQL developer, I have the following problems:

- I didn't get the REST data services option under connection menu.
- I'm getting an `authentication failed` error when trying for development under view - REST data services-developer menu.
- I get the `error 503 - service unavailable` when I hit the url http://localhost:8080/ords/ to run under view - REST data services - administration

How do I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you got through the 8 or 9 step Wizard, and you have ORDS running now on your machine.

Before you can connect or start publishing services, you need to setup a schema.

Step One: REST Enable a schema.

Login to where you want to publish a restful service.

Run this

```
BEGIN

    ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(p_enabled => TRUE,
                       p_schema => 'HR',
                       p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
                       p_url_mapping_pattern => 'hr',
                       p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);

    commit;
  END;
```

'HR' is your schema, and 'hr' will be on the URI.

If you connect to a DB where ORDS is installed, you should see this in SQL Developer (you might need to reconnect) - but the GUI item below will do the same thing as the code above.

[image]

*>>And I am also getting authentication failed error when trying for delopment under view - rest data services-developer menu.*

Don't use this. After you've rest enabled your schema (there's a right-click on your connection for that too), you should have a REST Services item on your connection tree. Build your services there. It's much more user friendly than our View > ORDS > REST Development interface.

[image]

Comment: i show you how to do this here - skip to about 5 minutes in to get to the GUI/IDE stuff in sql developer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAUJmiW1w2Y&index=2&list=PL_qNe_aTKkIXN3WW6HOq1O0ENOcH2TcFl

Comment: Thank you Smith for your detailed explanation. When I logged into the hr and tried to execute the command
[code] exec ords.enable_schema;[/code]
It's giving the error 
[code]identifier ords.enable_schema must be declared. [/code]
I couldn't get the rest enable option still under the connection menu. But ords is running fine in the system.
Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: are you in the right db? after an install, ORDS package should be granted execute to public